# df.to_parquet giving error - realloc of size 1073741824 failed

Tags: pandas, parquet

when I try to export df with 240,000,000 rows to parquet
i get an error

> realloc of size 1073741824 failed

I dont want to split the file.

can I use another solution?

Comment: What's you pandas version? Do you know which engine it is using (`pyarrow` or `fastparquet`)? You could try passing `row_group_size=1_000_000` to `to_parquet`, that would save data in small batches, but still in the same file.

Comment: my pandas version is '1.3.3'   .  I use auto engine . will it help if I use pyarrow or fastparquet?   what the disadvantage of using row_group_size?

Comment: when I use  row_group_size=1_000_000   , the error massge was -   realloc of size 2147483648 failed

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace? The `row_group_size` would just split the data within the parquet file in batches of that size. It shouldn't have a big overhead, unless if it's very small (in which case you have a lot of very small batches).